# Ionic changer setinterval delay dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, setinterval, resume, pause

Following is my code:

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
      this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
          this.appstatusonoff = 1;
      });

      this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
          this.appstatusonoff = 0;
      });
```

Second part:

```
this.run_scripts = setInterval(() => {
   this.getusers();
  }, 20000);
```

I want to change the interval 20000 dynamically. I want to use 60000 when `this.platform.pause` and 20000 when `this.platform.resume`.

Any ideas as to how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable on the Class level (global variable) and use that in setInterval command.

```
public intervaltimeOut = 20000 // by default value


this.run_scripts = setInterval(() => {
   this.getusers();
  }, this.intervaltimeOut );
```

change value of this.intervaltimeOut = 60000  whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks so much this solve my ploblem. For others persons who come in this post in the future,  i have put the this.intervaltimeOut = 60000; inside the function this.getusers();